# How do I get keyboard menu navigation to work under Gnome 3?

Tags: keyboard, menu, navigation

Keyboard interaction seems so broken to me the I must be doing something silly.

Simple scenario: `<Ctrl>-<Alt>-T` and I get a new terminal. I *click* "Terminal" and "Reset" and the terminal resets. So far, so good.

Same scenario, using only the keyboard: `<Ctrl>-<Alt>-T` and I get a new terminal. I'd like to access the "Terminal" menu with `<Alt>-T`, but that doesn't work. If I access it with the mouse, I'd like to trigger "Reset" by typing `r`. Doesn't work, either. However, if I press a cursor key (up or down), typing `r` works.

Now, why doesn't `<Alt>-T` access the "Terminal" menu and why doesn't `r` run the "Reset" command (without cursor keys to nudge it) and how can I get this very, very, very basic and widely used interaction style to work?

Or to put it another way, I want to "Paste" with `<Alt>-E p` instead of `<shift>-<control>-V`. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the option

*Edit → Preferences → General → Activate mnemonics*

[image]

---

Sorry for the spanish, I couldn't get the terminal in english with `LC_ALL=C`.

Comment: No worries, Spanish is perfect, as far as I'm concerned, and so is the solution. :) It boggles my mind that a setting like this would even exist, let alone be switched off by default. Anyway, thanks!